# How do I block all other processes on a Linux machine for XXX milliseconds?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-kernel, usb, alsa

I'm working with a Linux embedded SMP system that does audio I/O using ALSA and an external USB Audio device, using a 3.6.6. kernel. Problem: I'm getting infrequent (once every few weeks) system hiccups that are causing the audio stream to die. Although it's tough to be sure, the hiccups look like they lock up the entire system for a few dozens of milliseconds.

I can write ALSA code to recover after one of these hiccups, but since it's ALSA some trial and error will be required. Add that to having to wait weeks for a reoccurrence, and I'll be up a creek with a crowbar. I really need a way to cause the problem on demand.

I'd like to write a C program that runs as root and blocks all other processes on the system for a given number of milliseconds. I imagine it would involve disabling interrupts, doing a delay loop (since the timers will probably fail), and then restoring interrupts. But, I have to do it in such a way that the whole system doesn't go belly up.

Any ideas on how I would write such a program?

Comment: It would be nice to understand the root cause before trying to do a fix or work-around. What is the nature of the audio stream "die"? Does it happen only in your own application, or does it happen with standard ALSA utilities too such as `aplay`? If the latter, then there may be a driver bug that's worth fixing (or bringing to the attention of others to fix it).

Comment: The problem is that it happens every other week, or in one case after eight weeks. This means that the usual "observe problem, analyze, iterate" approach is just this side of useless. And, it happens in the depths of ALSA, which is a notoriously (at least in my engineering group) confusing and poorly-documented system. This means that careful inspection of the system is also unrewarding. (BTW, we're guessing this is ALSA bug  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=798844, which was purportedly fixed in kernel 3.6.2, but is still being reported.)

Comment: The problem is likely to be caused by some device driver that disables interrupts for too long. Anyway, on x86, you can get privileges to disable interrupts with `iopl()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on [CL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl)'s tip, and on information from http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/IO-Port-Programming, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long i, j;

    printf("About to lock system!\n");

    // Boost I/O privilege level
    iopl(3);

    // Clear interrupt flag, masking interrupts
    asm("cli");

    // Wait about a second (with some hijinks to keep
    // the loop from being optimized into oblivion)
    j = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 250000000; i++) {
        j *= i;
    }

    // Restore interrupt flag, restoring interrupts
    asm("sti");

    // Restore I/O privilege level
    iopl(0);

    printf("Phew! Survived!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When run as root, it works! Although not everything is suspended (and it's not clear to me what is and what isn't), enough locks up that my ALSA stream fails quite nicely. So, now I can stimulate the problem and ensure my code can handle it.

One note: I'd assumed that between the CLI and STI, system timing routines would fail due to the lack of interrupts. However, when just for the heck of it I tried usleep(), the timing code worked! But, the code as a whole actually didn't, because the call re-enabled interrupts, making the tool useless. Hence the use of a simple delay loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try raising the priority of your process and then using one of the "realtime" scheduling algorithms (e.g. SCHED_FIFO). This will help make sure that your process gets scheduled more consistently, even if other processes are running.

Comment: The app is running as root, nice'd by -20. Some (not all) of our threads are running as SCHED_FIFO. Still happens to all the threads.